# Which methods are called when an asterisk/double asterisk is applied to a Python object?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909472/which-of-dicts-methods-is-called-when-pythons-double-asterisk-operator-is-used) but doesn't contain any answers.

I'm creating a custom class that inherits from the native Python `dict` and want to implement some special behavior when an instance of my class is passed to a function with a signature like `def foo(*args,**kwargs)`.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), the relevant methods that have to be overloaded for this are `__iter__`, `__getitem__` and `__len__`, so I setup a basic example to verify what's happening behind the scenes:

```py
class A(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print("__getattribute__ called")
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        print("__iter__ called")
        return super(A, self).__iter__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("__getitem__ called")
        return super(A, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __len__(self):
        print("__len__ called")
        return super(A, self).__len__()

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args: ", args)
    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)


a = A()
a['a'] = 1

print("Calling foo() with A")
foo(a)
```

This just produces the following output:

```
Calling foo() with A
args:  ({'a': 1},)
kwargs:  {}
```

It seems that none of the required functions are being called. I overloaded `__getattribute__` additionally, just to check which/any class methods/members are being accessed, but nothing seems to be called. What exactly is happening here? I'm using Python 3.7 if that's relevant.

Comment: Try with `foo(**a)`

Comment: Doing so does invoke `__getitem__`, but what happens if I just call `foo(a)`? The operator still seems to be applied. I want to know how that's happening.

Comment: Which operator?

Comment: The astrisk/double asterisk.

Comment: If you call `foo(a)`, no unpacking is taking place. You’re just passing the object as an argument. `foo(*a)` is different to `foo(a)`.

Comment: `foo(a)` means foo is being called with `args == (a,)`, hence the ouput. `a` itself is not being unpacked in that process, however. `args` are the positional arguments, and you pass `a` as the first and only positional argument.

Comment: So this is just the `__repr__` or `__str__` method being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came across this question today because I was also searching for that answer. I notice though, that nobody has provided an answer and I could not find any answer online as well! Maybe my GoogleFu is not good enough, maybe it is a simple question, or simply nobody has put the effort to answer it.

Here is the answer then!

Let's define two classes.

A first one that inherits from `list`:

```py
class Foo(list):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print('__getattribute__ called')
        return super().__getattribute__(item)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        print('__iter__ is called')
        return super().__iter__()
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print('__getitem__ is called')
        return super().__getitem__(item)
    
    def __len__(self):
        print('__len__ is called')
        return super().__len__()
```

and a second one that inherits from dict:

```py
class Bar(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print('__getattribute__ called')
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        print('__iter__ is called')
        return super().__iter__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print('__getitem__ is called')
        return super().__getitem__(item)
    
    def __len__(self):
        print('__len__ is called')
        return super().__len__()
```

Then let's define a function to print a dict:

```py
def bar(a, b):
    print(f'a is {a} and b is {b}')
```

then, let's define our variables:

```py
my_list = Foo()
my_list.extend([1, 2])

my_dict = Bar()
my_dict.update({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

Then, let's see that get's printed!

```py
print(*a)
__iter__ is called
__len__ is called
1 2
```

and

```py
bar(**b)
__getattribute__ called
__getitem__ is called
__getitem__ is called
a is 1 and b is 2
```